# Is threatening a trespasser at gunpoint impermissible in UT?

Tags: firearms, utah, trespassing

The question is prompted by news video of a trespassing snowboarder threatened at gunpoint.

https://abcnews.go.com/US/video/dramatic-moment-snowboarder-stopped-gunpoint-private-property-107920296

If not, What effective remedy is available for Utah snowboard trespassers?

I am also wondering if there is any federal statute that governs the subject matter

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, its impermissible

The permitted use of threat of deadly force are spelled out in [76-2-402](https://le.utah.gov/xcode/title76/chapter2/76-2-s402.html) which says

> An individual is justified in threatening or using force against another individual when and to the extent that the individual reasonably believes that force or a threat of force is necessary to defend the individual or another individual against the imminent use of unlawful force.

From, the clip, it is evident that any belief the property owner had that force was necessary to protect themselves from the snowboarder was not reasonable, so the threat of force was not justified.

As to the effective remedy against snowboard trespassers: erect a fence or signs.

Without a clear indication that you are not permitted on the land (like a fence or signage), you are not trespassing until you are told you are. And, even then, you have a reasonable period of time to remove yourself before you commit trespass.

The snowboarder was never trespassing. He clearly stated he saw no signs (and I have no reason not to believe him) and he left as soon as possible after being told to.

Comment: And so the snowboarder, upon seeing a stranger pointing a gun at him and believing he was going to be shot, would likely have been justified in shooting the landowner?